# Can't import rememberTextMeasurer

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

My Android Studio is unable to find [`rememberTextMeasurer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/package-summary#rememberTextMeasurer(kotlin.Int)).

I thought I only needed to update to `ui-text:1.3.0-beta03`, but that didn't seem to work. What can I do to access `rememberTextMeasurer`?

In general I've found android packaging to be quite obscure. For example in the doc linked above, there doesn't seem to be anything that indicated in what version a feature was added, etc. Is there a better resource for figuring out dependencies and gradle configuration?

My current gradle script:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myApp"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlin.sourceSets.all {
        languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.3.1"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-text:1.3.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.2.1"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.2"
}
```

Comment: Provide your code pls

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm not sure what code I could provide that would help? All I'm calling is `val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()` inside a composable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rememberTextMeasurer()` is in `:ui` module of `androidx.compose.ui` library, while `TextMeasurer` class is in `ui-text`, so you have to update "androidx.compose.ui:ui" to latest. And androidx.compose.ui:ui pulls ui-text.

To have better visibility on dependencies, you can run `./gradlew yourModule:dependencies`.

You can also use the new [BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#using-the-bom) to organise dependencies easier.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this just by updating all the other compose packages to 1.3.0-beta03 too. I'm not sure why that was necessary though, and would appreciate anyone who could clarify.